# Reformatting numeric values without coercing to character

Tags: r

Take the following vector `x`.

```
x <- c(50.333, 195.333, 186, 214.333, 246.667)
```

The decimal places of `x` will **always** be one of either zero, 1/3, or 2/3 (i.e. 0.0, 0.333, or 0.667). I'd like to quickly change their respective decimals to the result of the following

```
> round(x %% 1/3, 1)
[1] 0.1 0.1 0.0 0.1 0.2
```

meaning that, with `x`

- if 0 is the decimal, it's still zero
- if 0.333 is the decimal, it changes to 0.1
- if 0.667 is the decimal, it changes to 0.2

Currently I'm clunkily converting to character, then back to numeric to get the following desired result...

```
> as.numeric(paste0(round(x, 0), sub("0", "", round(x %% 1/3, 1))))
[1]  50.1 195.1 186.0 214.1 247.2
```

Is there a mathematical way to do this without having to coerce to character?

Comment: Also maybe `floor(x) + round(x %% 1/3, 1)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg - yeah, that's probably the best way. Thanks.  Make it an answer if you want.

Comment: I've benchmarked it and it seems like `as.integer` is more efficient than `floor`, so probably should stick with @SimonGs solution

Comment: Maybe something more rigorous than `round(x %% 1/3, 1)` would be `round(3 * x) %% 3L / 10`. You can try plotting both with `x <- c(0, 1, 0.01)` to see what I mean. Also for fun, see `1/3 %% 1/3`.

Comment: Given the other comments, I'd suggest either doing what was suggested in the second answer and express this in integer thirds [ie, 14 outs recorded], or use a factor or string representation.  You're trying to express something in a human-readable way, good - but that's what character/string vectors are for.  Leaving something like this in numeric form is just a temptation to do math to it, which is a bad idea.

Comment: @Joe -  that is a very good point, thanks a lot.  But I'm using matrices for speed reasons, so it's kinda one or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I built onto your previous efforts and got some good results with this:

```
x <- c(50.333, 195.333, 186, 214.333, 246.667)

stripDecimal <- function(x){
  y <- as.integer(x)
  z <- round(x %% 1/3, 1)
  y+z
}

stripDecimal(x)
[1]  50.1 195.1 186.0 214.1 246.2
```

Comment: This is a good idea. +1 Just a note, the last line could be just `y+z` and `sapply` isn't necessary since all functions in `stripDecimal`'s body are vectorized. `stripDecimal(x)` will do it.

Answer (score -1):

Why not simply get the fraction for each number and divide that by .333 (round up) and then divide by 10 to get the transformed number you want.  Mathmatically:

- intpart = floor (number);
- fracpart = number -intpart
- newfracpart = (fracpart / .333)
- new number = intpart + newfracpart/10.0

I am not sure why you want to encode your numbers this way ... any particular reason?

You might consider changing the number to the "number of thirds" and using modulo 3 to get the factional part and number /3 for the int

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  The reason is that these are major league baseball "innings pitched". They're most commonly displayed as 0.1 if you pitched 1/3 of an inning, 0.2 for 2/3, etc.

Comment: @RichardScriven, In R code, it could look like this (took the liberty to make it a function): `convert <- function(x){number <- x; intpart <- floor(number); fracpart <- number - intpart; newfracpart <- fracpart / (1 / 3); newnumber <- intpart + newfracpart / 10}; return(newnumber)`. Feel free to break lines between semi-colons in order to better visualize the program.